# extending more than one classes in java

Tags: java

I have a class in my java code that extends `SwingWorker<Void,Void>` class, now I want to extend only `mouseClicked()` method of `MouseAdapter` class but I can not extend `MouseAdapter` class because I have already extended SwingWorker, is there any other way to use the `mouseClicked()` method of MouseAdapter class? because if I will implement MouseListener then I will need to override all the methods of MouseListener but I need only mouseClicked.

Comment: smells like bad *design*. Recheck your design.

Comment: Use `interfaces` and aggregation. Otherwise (although not recommended) you can use multilevel inheritance.

Answer (score 5):

HINT: Showing your code will help us understand your issues.

Anyway, from what I read, it seems you intend to do something like

```
public MyClass extends SwingWorker<Void, Void>, MouseAdapter {
```

You just cannot have multiple inheritance in Java, so that won't work.

You have two options:

- make `MyClass` **implement** `MouseListener` interface. Since it is an interface, it will be not considered multiple inheritance. You will have to provide an implementation to all of the interface methods, although the empty implementation will be enough.
- create a different class (probably an inner class) to implement the mouse listener. It may or may not be suited to your proposits, since it is not clear what you want to do.

NOTE: In general (without knowing your particular needs), the second approach would usually be more sensible, as defining the logic in multiple classes is more likely to achieve the "Single Responsability" principle (a class does one thing, and just one).

Answer (score 4):

It seems that you have to implement all methods from MouseListener:

```
public class YourClass extends SwingWorker<Void,Void> implements MouseListener {
   ...
}
```

The other option is to use [composition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance) instead of [inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance). Just create field in YourClass which extends MouseAdapter:

```
public class YourClass extends SwingWorker<Void, Void> {
    MouseAdapter mouseAdapter = new MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            // Your implementation here
        }
    };
    ...
}
```

Comment: but I need only mouseClicked meyhod

Comment: @Shafu : Then you can use composition. See my edits to this answer.